# Convert int to date in SQL Server vs Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

EXCEL: When I format the number 43466 as a date I get 1/1/2019

SQL Server: `CAST(43466 AS DATETIME)` yields Jan 3 2019

Which is correct?

How can I get the correct date in SQL Server?

Comment: dateadd(day, date, -2)? There's no "correct", there's only different starting points for comparison. SQL is adding 43466 days to 01/01/1900 which comes to Jan 3 2019.

Comment: Note: While 0 as a date is 01/01/1900 in SQL, it's the 0th of January 1900 in Excel - 1 "day" earlier even though it's not a real date - and excel also includes February 29 1900 as a date (60) even though 1900 was not a leap year so it's also not a real date, ergo there's a 2-day discrepancy.